# Implementing Security on Sessions

Tags: php, security, session

How can I secure the data that my session posts so that to reduce injections?

Is there perhaps something I need to add when I use $_SESSION[''] = $var; or when I retrieve the data by $var = $_SESSION[''];?

Comment: I think Paolo Bergantino is right, but if you can be clearer on where the data is being accessed that would be helpful  (post, get, db, etc).

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by secure? It depends on what you are going to eventually do with the data and the origin of the data, and in that case it doesn't vary from what you do for other variables. If you are planning on displaying the data on the `$_SESSION` array, you should escape it with [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) or [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) to prevent XSS, etc. If you are using the data in the `$_SESSION` array in a query, you should [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) it (or, even better, use bound parameters) to prevent injection. If you have full control of the data that is going into the `$_SESSION`, then there's not much to worry about.